# C++ x = P > Q equivalent in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a C++ program to C#. I came across a line of statement as below.

```
int X;
int P = 10;
int Q = 5;

X = P < Q;
```

It make sense to me if X is a bool value. However X is an integer. I am wondering what the output of X would be. It might be a very basic syntax in C++. Sorry for my ignorance. I am after an equivalent statement in C#. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# the assignment would not be permitted, because (as you guessed) the expression `P < Q` would be of the type `bool`.  This C# code would be roughly equivalent:

```
int X;
int P = 10;
int Q = 5;

X = (P < Q) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense to me now. If I have statement X = P= !Q, is that going to give me a 1 for X?

Comment: In C that is going to give you a non-zero value, yes.  You can use the ternary operator as I did above to achieve this result in C#.  Of course, you could also store the result in a `bool` variable, which may or may not be what you are after.

Comment: The result in C or C++ is perfectly well defined.  The <, <=, >, >=, ==, and != operators all yield 1 if the condition is true, 0 if it's false.  (When a condition is being *tested*, any non-zero value is true.)

Comment: @Keith: My understanding was that the relational operators were only required to return zero if false and non-zero otherwise.  I could certainly be wrong on that.

Comment: Are these 2 statements will produce identical result, X = P!=Q and X= P= !Q?  I know the first statement can be converted as X=P!=Q?1:0 . Is that the same syntax for X = P= !Q too? Thanks

Comment: `P=!Q` means "negate Q and assign the result to P, then also to X".  Yes, you can perform the same operation, but I'm skeptical at the value of such a double-assignment in this context.

Comment: @cdhowie: [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5.8p6: "Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false."; 6.5.9p1 says the same for == and !=.  (Don't think of it as being wrong; think of it as a learning opportunity!)

Comment: @Keith: Nod -- I answer according to the knowledge I have acquired or inferred, but am always open to correction.  That is, after all, how one improves.

Answer (score 3):

if you want a boolean result:

```
bool X = P < Q;
```

... if you want an integer:

```
int X = P < Q ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

bool to integer converion in c++ is: true is 1, false is 0. In c# this conversion doesen't exists.

```
int X;
int P = 10;
int Q = 5;

X = (P < Q)?(1):(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, this conversion doesn't exist implicitly or explicitly, but you can use the `Convert` class

```
int X;
int P = 10;
int Q = 5;

X = Convert.ToInt32(P < Q);
```

But using either a `bool` or `X = P < Q? 1:0` is best.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `X` would be 1 (0 is false, 1 (or any non-zero int) is true).